# What is the time complexity of the following method in terms of Big-O notation?

Tags: algorithm, methods, big-o, time-complexity

Help me solve the time complexity of this method below here:

```
void method(int n, int[] array)
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;

  for(; i < n; ++i)
  {
    while(j < n && array[i] < array[j])
    {
      j++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the time complexity is? It may be better for you to guess and your guess corrected/adjusted.

Comment: This smells a bit like homework.

Answer (score 2):

The runtime is O(n).

In some iterations of the outer loop the inner loop might progress several times and at other it might not progress at all, but in total there will be at most `n` increases of `j`. As this is independent of when (which values of `i`) this happens, you might say this is O(n) for the outer loop plus O(n) for the (up to) `n` increases of `j`. O(n) + O(n) = O(n).

This is contrary to the typical 'loop inside loop' which would perform `n` iterations of the inner loop *for every iteration* of the outer loop and thus be O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2).